# Create a Gem for Models to be shared between two applications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have never done this before and am not sure where to begin. I have two applications, one read and the other read/write. I have been advised that I can share the same database between the two applications and that I should create a gem of my models from the read/write app to be used in my read only app.

This sounds like a great solution as it means I won't have to duplicate my code between the two apps. Where to start though? I would really appreciate an explanation and some guidance on what to do here, almost a mini how-to guide if possible, or at least somewhere to look?

So having done some more reading I can see that you can use Bundler to create a gem

```
bundle gem name-of-my-gem
```

and I can use the gem like so, by placing it in each application

```
gem "name-of-my-gem", path: "path/to/gem/dir"
```

How do I actually tell it which of my models I want to put into a gem though?

Comment: I don't see why the models shell put into the gem?

Comment: so i dont have to create all the models in each application, if it is a bad practice then please suggest your method, however i would like to see this through and create the gem with models, if not only to learn something :)

Comment: you have stored model in the gem, correct? and you have to change its code? if yes, why did you say about *put into gem*, because I thought about a data.

Comment: the way i see it is that all the associations and methods for each model get bundled into a gem? I can then have access to these via the gem? is this correct?

Comment: Generally the gem is just code, in some case non-database data. I don't the obstacle to use the gem, in a project, because on the project's head is to control DB data, not on the gem's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How you structure the gem is pretty much up to you, but here's how I would start:

```
name-of-my-gem/
.. lib/
.... name-of-my-gem.rb
.... models/
...... all_of_your_models
```

Your models gem should have a `.rb` file that loads any models stored in it. If this file is named after the gem and placed in the `lib/` directory of the gem, it should be auto-loaded by bundler. This file might look something like this:

```
require "models/customer"
require "models/order"
# ...
```

You might also do something fancier here, like grab the list of files in the models directory and load each one so you don't have to add each new model to this file. Up to you.

Each `models/` file would look exactly the same as a model in your rails app:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  # ...
end
```

You can copy any model classes you want to share out of `app/models/` in the rails app they currently reside in and paste them into `models/` in your gem. Then, you simply need to update the gem in each app (run `bundle update name-of-my-gem` in each) and you should be able to take the model out of `app/models/` and it should still work since it will be loaded from your gem.

One downside of this approach is that rails can no longer reload the model after you make changes. After changing a model in your gem you will need to run `bundle update name-of-my-gem`, and restart the rails server. I would suggest fleshing out most of a model's functionality in one app first to take advantage of rails code-reloading, and when its pretty stable move it into the gem.

You could also give your gem code-reloading powers, but that gets rather complicated and I've never done that.

Comment: thank you so much, that makes sense, so im literally taking a copy of my models and putting them into the gem (will do once they are finalised)...might be a daft question but from where do i create the gem? outside of the application or within my read/write (app1) ? you have been a great help by the way

Comment: You create the gem outside of your application. In essence your models become their own library. I would of course suggest keeping your gem in a git repository. You can then point each app's `Gemfile` at the git repo instead of the local path to the gem: `gem "name-of-my-gem", git: "git@somewhere.com:user/repo.git"`

Comment: makes perfect sense...you have just cleared up a lot there for me with creating gems, if i could give you more points i would...thank you so much

Comment: last question, if i create a new directory locally for this, do i need a gemfile any other gems? or do i just setup the file structure like you have in the answer? and once completed push that to a repo?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're asking. Your models gem wouldn't have to have a Gemfile, though it would need at least a gemspec file. `bundle gem gem-name` should create a directory `gem-name/` with all the basic "stuff" a gem has to have with a decent directory structure as well. Each rails app should have its own Gemfile, with an entry in each one for your models gem. If you point to the gem's git repo, then, yes, you will need to push any changes to that repo before `bundle update gem-name` can update the gem for each rails app.

Comment: You probably don't need to list any dependencies in your model gem's Gemfile or gemspec, if that's what you were asking. Those can stay pretty bare. You might want to add dependencies eventually if you want the model gem to work on its own, outside of a rails app. You might go this route if you want your models gem to also contain the tests for your models. In that case the gem will need to depend on `activerecord` and any other gems your models use and have its own test database configuration. You could also leave tests in one of the rails apps for simplicity.

Comment: well for know its only going to be used for this app, so no need for gemfile like you say as the app will have everything, this will literally be a library for the two apps to share models... I get it now :)

Comment: @CarlZulauf What is the best way to setup CI with a model gem? Especially since the schema.rb is going to be in a separate gem, how do you setup your test infrastructure?